# How do I authenticate API Gateway in AWS with AccessKey and SecretKey

Tags: python, go, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-go

I have an API Gateway and I used to pass `awsauth` (see below) parameter using the `aws4auth` Python package like `AWS4Auth(AK, SK, region, service=execute-api)`.

But, I'm unable to find a similar package for Go. Is there any AWS-SDK in Go?

Sample Python code of what I'd like to do in Go:

```
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
awsauth = AWS4Auth(AK, SK, region, service=execute-api)
requests.post(host,auth=awsauth,json=document,headers=headers)
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/apigateway/

Comment: Have you tried [aws-signer-v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/signer/v4/)?. `func (v4 Signer) Sign(r *http.Request, body io.ReadSeeker, service, region string, signTime time.Time) (http.Header, error)`